# Phpmailer "Message has been sent successfully" but not delivered mail?

Tags: php, phpmailer

When i try this code to send email, i get 
"*Message has been sent successfully*" but when i check my yahoo inbox and spam folder i see that mail is not delivered.

```
function sendmail(){
//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//From email address and name
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->From = "my.mail@yahoo.com";
$mail->FromName = "Name";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("my.mail@yahoo.com", "Recepient Name");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

var_dump($mail);

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
}
sendmail();
?>
```

When i **var_dump**($mail) to see what params are setted i get this:

```
object(PHPMailer)[1]
  public 'Version' => string '5.2.14' (length=6)
  public 'Priority' => null
  public 'CharSet' => string 'iso-8859-1' (length=10)
  public 'ContentType' => string 'text/html' (length=9)
  public 'Encoding' => string '8bit' (length=4)
  public 'ErrorInfo' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'From' => string 'my.mail@yahoo.com' (length=22)
  public 'FromName' => string 'Name' (length=6)
  public 'Sender' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'ReturnPath' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Subject' => string 'Subject Text' (length=12)
  public 'Body' => string '<i>Mail body in HTML</i>' (length=24)
  public 'AltBody' => string 'This is the plain text version of the email content' (length=51)
  public 'Ical' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'MIMEBody' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'MIMEHeader' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'mailHeader' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'WordWrap' => int 0
  public 'Mailer' => string 'mail' (length=4)
  public 'Sendmail' => string '/usr/sbin/sendmail' (length=18)
  public 'UseSendmailOptions' => boolean true
  public 'PluginDir' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'ConfirmReadingTo' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Hostname' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'MessageID' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'MessageDate' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  public 'Port' => int 25
  public 'Helo' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'SMTPSecure' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'SMTPAutoTLS' => boolean true
  public 'SMTPAuth' => boolean false
  public 'SMTPOptions' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'Username' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Password' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'AuthType' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Realm' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Workstation' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'Timeout' => int 300
  public 'SMTPDebug' => int 0
  public 'Debugoutput' => string 'echo' (length=4)
  public 'SMTPKeepAlive' => boolean false
  public 'SingleTo' => boolean false
  public 'SingleToArray' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'do_verp' => boolean false
  public 'AllowEmpty' => boolean false
  public 'LE' => string '
' (length=1)
  public 'DKIM_selector' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'DKIM_identity' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'DKIM_passphrase' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'DKIM_domain' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'DKIM_private' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'action_function' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'XMailer' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'smtp' => null
  protected 'to' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'my.mail@yahoo.com' (length=22)
          1 => string 'Recepient Name' (length=14)
  protected 'cc' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'bcc' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'ReplyTo' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'all_recipients' => 
    array (size=1)
      'my.mail@yahoo.com' => boolean true
  protected 'RecipientsQueue' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'ReplyToQueue' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'attachment' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'CustomHeader' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'lastMessageID' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'message_type' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'boundary' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'language' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'error_count' => int 0
  protected 'sign_cert_file' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'sign_key_file' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'sign_extracerts_file' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'sign_key_pass' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'exceptions' => boolean false
  protected 'uniqueid' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: You're using `isMail()` (which is the default anyway), so your message will be sent via your local mail server. When it reports success, it means it delivered it successfully *to your local mail server*, not any further. To find out what happened after that, look in your mail server log file, usually `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: When i try to access /var/log/mail.log by ssh, i get permission denied message...

Comment: Use `sudo`? Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: I tried this tail -n 100 /var/log/mail.log. Yes, cloudways server.

Comment: Intersting is that wordpress newsletter plugin can send mails, but some other mail plugins and out wordpress mail() and phpmailer can't.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set gmail as you SMTP server. Among the things you have to do for this is: set `$mail -> host = smtp.mail.yahoo.com`. Besides this you need to set the port to 587. Check out google to see how to set yahoo as a smtp server and how to authenticate yourself.

Comment: Can i use phpmailer without authentication?

Comment: No probably not. At least I could not send an email with gmail without authentication. It probably works the same for Yahoo (but to be sure you need you could try sending with and without authentication).

Comment: This is not true. You do not have to use SMTP.